# ¿Como detectar el timbrado de una llamada saliente en Android usando Visualizer?

Tags: android

Actualmente necesito capturar el momento en que comienza a escucharse el timbre de una llamada saliente por el altavoz de un teléfono Android. Según [Abeer Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6056491/abeer-ahmad) en ["How to identify the ringing state of outgoing call in android"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910570/how-to-identify-the-ringing-state-of-outgoing-call-in-android/36103972#36103972), una solución sería detectar el cambio de frecuencia del sonido emitido (de 0 a el valor correspondiente al timbre) usando la clase [Visualizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html). Sin embargo, ningún valor de frecuencia distinto a 0 (silencio) es detectado mientras efectúo una llamada. Lo cual no se corresponde a lo que ocurre cuando el móvil emite otro sonido, como puede ser la reproducción de una pista de audio, donde los valores de frecuencia si son detectados. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar, o darme una solución alternativa?

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener listener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) { }
                    @Override
                    public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                        for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++) {
                            if (bytes[i] != 0) {
                              Log.i("INFO","FRECUENCIA:"+bytes[i]);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(listener, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, true);
```

La version de android donde lo estoy probando es Android Jellybean (API 17).

Comment: Tambien he probado con Android Lollipop y obtengo los mismos resultados

Comment: Wow... Por favor, alguien que responda esta pregunta, se lo agradecería muchísimo... tengo el mismo problema y necesito realmente resolverlo. Iba a publicar una pregunta similar y vi esta con cero respuestas. Por favor, alguien que sepa!!!!