# Android: Detectar el momento en que una llamada saliente comienza a timbrar en el otro teléfono

Tags: android

Necesito saber si hay alguna manera (aunque ya estoy casi convencida de que no la hay) de detectar cuando una llamada saliente comienza a timbrar en el teléfono de destino.

Lo que necesito saber específicamente es justo **EL INSTANTE** en que comienza a timbrar la llamda en el teléfono de la otra persona, y luego, si es posible, la duración de la misma antes de que sea atendida o colgada. Esto último da igual ya que solo necesito el tiempo en que está siendo timbrado sin importar si se descuelga o se cuelga.

Llevo mucho tiempo buscando en google y las soluciones que dan son 0. También he buscado en SO en inglés, como por ejemplo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320631/programmatically-detect-when-outgoing-call-starts-ringback-tone-ringing-to-the/45864751#45864751) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534778/detect-the-time-when-a-phone-starts-ringing-for-outgoing-calls), donde prácticamente soy la única que les he dado respuestas diciendo que es imposible hacerlo (basado en mi experiencia y mi investigación por todo internet), pero quisiera saber si alguien de esta comunidad conoce alguna forma de hacer esto.

[Esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52285/como-detectar-el-timbrado-de-una-llamada-saliente-en-android-usando-visualizer) es otra pregunta similar, de SOes, y también sin respuestas. Lo que en esta se pregunta de una manera mas específica, usando la clase `Visualizer` y yo pregunto desde un punto de vista más general, o sea por cualquier vía que exista.

Concluyendo, todas las preguntas que he encontrado en otros sitios sobre este tema están absolutamente sin respuestas y no he logrado encontrar una manera de lograrlo. Por favor si alguien conoce una manera de hacer esto, se lo agradecería muchísimo, ya que llevo bastante tiempo con este problema. Gracias por la atención. Saludos

Comment: Hola Adríana, desafortunadamente como lo comentas en un post en SOen: **"Es imposible detectar esto mediante una aplicación que no es de sistema"**. Sinceramente no he tratado de realizarlo mediante una aplicación de sistema.

Comment: @Jorgesys Si, luego de tanto buscar, eso mismo creo yo, pero dejo la pregunta aquí por si alguien conoce alguna manera alternativa de hacerlo, ya que nadie había preguntado todavía en esta comunidad. Tal vez alguien aquí sepa... No he perdido la esperanza

Comment: A ver...soy novato en el desarrollo Android, llegue a este hilo porq tambien llevo tiempo pensando en una app para dar timbres (solamente), (lo usamos mucho en mi pais), se me ha ocurrido algo auque pudiera ser un tanto inexacto; en la telefonia fija 1 timbre dura 2 seg. y el espacio entre timbres dura 4 seg segun DTMF, habria q ver si esto mismo sucede en telefonia movil, de modo q pudiera calcularse teniendo en cuenta estos tiempos, el tiempo en q se quiere cortar; el tema es q, al menos en mi pais el comienzo del 1er timbre no siempre es el mismo, todo depende de como este el canal

Comment: de comunicaciones, por ejemplo en horarios pico el 1er timbre demora mas en comenzar...este comentario q sirva de idea porq estoy convencido q en programacion casi todo se puede

Comment: @Arq, es válida tu sugerencia pero es que en mi país suele haber muy mala cobertura en la mayoría de los lugares, y el primer timbre puede empezar en cualquier momento, lo mismo al instante que 10 segundos despues de esperar con el teléfono en el oído, entonces no me sirve tu idea. Gracias. Saludos

Comment: Y además lo que necesito conocer es el momento en que empieza a dar el primer timbre, y no cuanto dura un timbre o el espacio entre timbres.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no es posible, cuando realizas una llamada desde un móvil esa llamada es recogida por la antena que da servicio de la operadora del móvil y llega a su central de conmutación, si el móvil al que llamas es de la misma operadora ya envía la llamada desde la central hasta la antena que da servicio al móvil destino y si es de otra operadora la envía a la central de la otra operadora y es ella la que manda la llamada a la antena que sea. Contando el tiempo desde que se emite la llamada opino que no es muy preciso ya que si hay saturación en las líneas de los operadores o mismo si existe algún problema de enrutamiento de la llamada o el enlace entre las distintas operadoras está caído, puede darse el caso de que en realidad no se esté realizando correctamente la llamada o tarde más de la cuenta en llegar al móvil destino.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno yo creo que sí hay una manera, en Android hay un `Action Intent` que te pueden ser útil:

- [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED):

> Broadcast intent action indicating that the call state on the device has changed.
>
> The EXTRA_STATE extra indicates the new call state. If the new state is RINGING, a second extra EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER provides the incoming phone number as a String.

La idea es usar `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` para saber el instante cuando entra una nueva llamada. [Aquí hay un ejemplo de como hacerlo](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61). El sistema te provee el número de la persona que esta llamando, así que puedes usarlo para filtrar las llamadas que te interesan.

Si no estas familiarizada con `BroadcastReceivers` te explico un poco. Al registrar tu app con el intent `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`, le estas diciendo al sistema que tú quieres ser notificada cuando hay "Un cambio en el estado de llamada del teléfono". Al momento que ocurra esa acción el sistema notificara tu app y ejecutara el código que tienes declarado sin importar si tu app el usuario la esta usando o no.

Comment: Hola, yo tambien he preguntado lo mismo en stackoverflow. A lo que te refieres es solo para llamadas entrantes. Sin embargo, Adriana pregunta por detectar el momento en que se escucha el tono de timbrado cuando haces una llamada a un contacto en tu movil. Desafortunadamente actualmente no existe un estado para indicar esto de la forma que sugieres.